# Uploading images to a server with blob

Tags: asp.net, azure, vue.js, blob

I have both asp.net API and vue.js Front. I want to upload images to my blob azure storage. Is it better to do it on API side? I mean send image to API and from API to blob Azure or directly from vue.js to blob azure?

Comment: It depends on how much you trust your user, and thier front end, ideally not in a least trust world

Answer (score 1):

Ideally we should try to send the image as POST to the API in ASP.NET and then call the API for uploading the image.
Instead of taking the image directly and uploading, we must check if the file is not corrupted (or any other issue) and then upload it.

In .NET, try out the below code:

```
string loc = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/" + location;
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(*connection_string*);
CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference(*container_name*);

container.CreateIfNotExists();
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(*blobName*);
blob.UploadFromFile(loc);
```